# Libreoffice Writer, editing bibliography entries is generating a new reference for each modification

Tags: libreoffice

I placed several bibliography entries in my document, I modified the biblio .odb file table using Base and I'm adding citations through insert > table of contents and index > bibliography entry.

However, I have the same bibliography entry several times in the document, and I want to modify it to manually change the page number for each of them, but every modification creates a new entry in the reference list, and I just need one entry there.

In other words, my reference list ended with duplicated entries for each modification I made.

¿How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any slightly professional referencing work, the build-in bibliographic system of LibreOffice is not adequate and fundamentally flawed by design — I do not wish to show disregard: it is actually software developed in the nineties, but developed has never continued to bring it to current standards.

I recommend moving to [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/), which is like LibreOffice Free Software. You maintain your references in a database system that is infinitely more powerful than the system of LO, whereas the LibreOffice plugin provides cite-while-you-write facility in LO.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I was reviewing the Libreoffice Writer documentation and in the Chapter 15, Tables of Contents, Indexes, Bibliographies, at the very end they say:

"If you find Writer’s bibliography feature too limited, you may wish to try Zotero, a free and open source tool, available for macOS, Windows, and Linux. It is reported to work well with Writer (https://www.zotero.org/)" (LibreOffice The Document Foundation, 2023)

References
LibreOffice The Document Foundation. (2023, February). Writer Guide 7.5. https://books.libreoffice.org/en/WG75/WG7515-TOCsIndexesBiblios.html